# Blank selection column when using Selection.MultiSelect on Grid, TreeGrid in Vaadin14

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

This is in a project that was migrated from Vaadin 8 to 14. This happens even when I do a black grid with lorem filler in it. Here is an example of the problem in action:
[image: screen shot of problem]

Creating any grid and setting it to multi-selection mode yields this problem. For example, the code at https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-elements/1.0.0/vaadin-grid/demo/selection.html#toc_1_selection_modes leads to this problem for me.

Comment: Can you please show code or provide a sample to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli for me, creating any grid in multi-selection mode creates this problem. for example, https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-elements/1.0.0/vaadin-grid/demo/selection.html#toc_1_selection_modes

Comment: Can you checkout this and try the examples there: https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/selection

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes using that code still leads to the blank selection column for me

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Are the contents in the DOM tree but perhaps wrongly positioned or having some other style issue, or are the contents missing altogether?

Comment: @AnnaKoskinen the selection column was there, it just was not styled and javascript stuff was not working. I explained what happened below for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, we manually run each `vaadin.flow.server.startup` initializer whenever we start our app in dev mode in Eclipse. I forgot to include this detail, as I wasn't aware of it at the time.

The problem was that we weren't running a `DevModeInitializer` for the `GridSelectionColumn` class in the initializer for our app, so none of the `@NpmPackage`, `@JsModule`, `@CssImport`, or `@Theme` annotations for that class were being included.

Once we included `GridSelectionColumn.class` in our initialization, the selection columns looked fine.